# Django CBV how to handle different pk value on 2 models?

Tags: python, django

Having difficulty Django CBV DetailView to be able to incoporate with Create,Update& Delete View:
I have two models, the 2nd model have a ForeignKey from the first one: How can I differentiate their pk value on their urls.py. I encounter error:404 when trying to detailView of the pk on the 2nd model. Thank you very much.

## Models:

```
class Rtana(models.Model):
    rsc_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,unique=True)
    rsc = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    cc = models.CharField(max_length=32,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.rsc_name , self.rsc)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("app7_cbv:details",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
class Rt(models.Model):
        rt_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,unique=True)
        rsc_no = models.ForeignKey(Rtana,related_name="route",on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
        rt_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.rt_name
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("app7_cbv:rtdetails",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

## Urls:

```
app_name = "app7_cbv"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^list$',views.Rtana_List_View.as_view(),name="list"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.Rtana__Detail_View.as_view(),name="details"),
    url(r'^create/$',views.Rtana_Create_View.as_view(),name="create"),
    url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.Rtana_Update_View.as_view(),name="update"),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.Rtana_Delete_View.as_view(),name="delete"),
    url(r'^rtlist$',views.Rt_List_View.as_view(),name="rtlist"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.Rt_Detail_View.as_view(),name="rtdetails"),
    url(r'^rtcreate/$',views.Rt_Create_View.as_view(),name="rtcreate"),
]
```

## views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,"index.html")
class Rtana_List_View(ListView):
    model = models.Rtana
    context_object_name = "rtana_list"
class Rtana__Detail_View(DetailView):
    model = models.Rtana
    context_object_name = "rtana_detail"
    template_name = "app7_cbv/rtana_detail.html"
class Rt_List_View(ListView):
    model = models.Rt
    context_object_name = "rt_list"
class Rt_Detail_View(DetailView):
    model = models.Rt
    context_object_name = "rt_detail"
    template_name = "app7_cbv/rt_detail.html"
class Rtana_Create_View(CreateView):
    model = models.Rtana
    fields = ('rsc_name','rsc','cc')
class Rtana_Update_View(UpdateView):
    model = models.Rtana
    fields = "__all__"
class Rtana_Delete_View(DeleteView):
    model = models.Rtana
    success_url = reverse_lazy("app7_cbv:list")
class Rt_Create_View(CreateView):
    model = models.Rt
    fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally namespace the models as "path components". I'll use a much used pattern:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^rtana/$', views.Rtana_List_View.as_view(),name="list"),
    url(r'^rtana/create/$', views.Rtana_Create_View.as_view(),name="create"),
    url(r'^rtana/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.Rtana__Detail_View.as_view(),name="details"),
    url(r'^rtana/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/', views.Rtana_Update_View.as_view(),name="update"),
    url(r'^rtana/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', views.Rtana_Delete_View.as_view(),name="delete"),
    url(r'^rt/$',views.Rt_List_View.as_view(),name="rtlist"),
    url(r'^rt/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.Rt_Detail_View.as_view(),name="rtdetails"),
    url(r'^rt/create/$',views.Rt_Create_View.as_view(),name="rtcreate"),
]
```

Comment: thank you so much for the advise, it is working perfectly fine now. thanks again Melvyn.